# Topology of open and closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Since any open set A is basically the interior of the set A itself, and the boundary of a set is basically the end points of the set being that it could be in the set A or the complement of A, then is A-BdA = IntA and is A-IntA= BdA

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering in the context suggested in the post (that $A$ is an arbitrary subset.). The title makes it a little confusing as to whether or not closed sets are involved.

No, the closure $\overline{A}$ is the disjoint union of the boundary $\partial A$ and the interior $A^\circ$.  It is perfectly possible for a boundary point to be outside of $A$, so you only have $A\setminus A^\circ\subseteq \partial A$.  Just consider the half-open interval $(0,1]$ in $\mathbb R$, for example. Of course, if $A$ is closed then you do have equality.

Somewhat paradoxically, the other equation *does* happen to be true: $A^\circ = A\setminus \partial A=\overline{A}\setminus\partial A$. This is something you can do as an easy exercise.

Comment: Whether closed sets are involved, if the statement does not hold for the open sets, doesn't that automatically disprove the statement?

Comment: I don't understand your comment or the question you're asking in the comment. Can you reformulate?

Comment: In terms of proofs especially for a theorem it has to hold for the open and closed sets if we're just looking at it in terms of A∘ and BdA. Like if we say that the interior of a set is the set without the boundaries then that has to hold for both open and closed sets. so if we say that a set without its interior if the boundary, then since it does not hold for an open set because an open set A - A∘ = ∅. and since the boundaries of an open set is in the complement of the set, then that one does not hold.

Comment: @Rlouis82 Yes, I think I agree with you that it is easy to produce open subsets of $\mathbb R$ which break that first proposition, and so it is not true in general.

Comment: @Rlouis82 Also, I wanted to comment that not just any open set would suffice to disprove it. Some open sets do not have a boundary.  For example, the entire space is such an open set (it is closed too) and it satisfies the one I disproved.

Answer (score 1):

$\partial (A)=Fr(A)=Bd(A)=\bar A\cap \overline {A^c},$ where $A^c$ is the complement of $A.$

[ $Fr$ is for Frontier. The LaTex for $\partial$ is \partial$\;$.]

If $A$ is open then $A^c$ is closed, so $A^c=\overline {A^c}$, and so $$\bar A\setminus A=\bar A\cap A^c=\bar A\cap \overline {A^c}=\partial (A).$$

If $A$ is any subset of any space $X,$ the trio $Int(A),Int(A^c), \partial (A)$ are pair-wise disjoint and their union is $X,$ where $Int(A)$ denotes the interior of $A$, also written $int(A)$ or $A^o$.

Comment: I sometimes try to write \int(A) for the interior of $A,$ but I get $\int(A)$.